# Uses for protected Throwable Constructor

Tags: java, exception, throwable

Since Java 7, the `java.lang.Throwable` class has a new `protected` constructor:

```
protected Throwable(String message, Throwable cause,
                    boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace)
```

It seems to give fine-grained control about whether or not stack traces should be computed and suppression is allowed. But in what situations can this be considered useful? Are there any performance benefits when throwing such an exception without stack trace computation?

Comment: There are big performance improvements if you don't generate a stack trace. Look for the write-up on [javaperformance.info](http://java-performance.info/throwing-an-exception-in-java-is-very-slow/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this more or less philosophical question. I was thinking about that and I can imagine a couple of scenarios:

1. You raise exceptions extremely rapidly, e.g. hundreds of time per second. It could be the legacy code, and you cannot change this, but you could suppress stacktrace building, this would gain you some performance boost.
2. You have implemented your own stacktrace mechanism. I saw concurrent applications with very complicated logic where stacktraces say nothing about the root cause of the problem. However I didn't see any alternative stacktrace implementations.